# How do I request a Read Receipt in a mail merge?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am doing a mail merge operation with VBA code from [this github](https://github.com/sotirop/mergelook).

It consists basically in a loop that should create objects called `OutlookMailItem` from an Outlook .oft template file and fill the template fields with data from an Excel file.

I set the property `ReadReceiptRequested = True` of `OutlookMailItem`, but test mails sent to my address don't show any confirmation request.

The steps of the creation of the OutlookMailItem:

```
 Dim OutLookApp As Object
 Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
 '....
 Do Until (a condition)
    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    '...
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(workFile)
    With OutLookMailItem
       '...
       .ReadReceiptRequested = True
       '...
    End With
 '...
 Loop


'where workfile is an existing and already initialised file
```

Maybe `ReadReceiptRequested = True` doesn't work because OutlookMailItem isn’t exactly a MailItem?

Comment: Have you checked your own Outlook settings to make sure you haven't selected the option to never send a read receipt in response to a read receipt request? If that option is selected, you won't see any confirmation request.

Comment: What do you see with `?ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).ReadReceiptRequested` in the immediate pane? 1- Select the item in the Sent folder. 2- Select the item in the Inbox.

Comment: @Sam I checked my settings: always send read receipt request.

Comment: @niton can you tell me please where do I have to use that line of command? My VBA knowledge is limited.

Comment: Immediate Window https://v1.nitrocdn.com/zciqOWZgDznkuqFpvIJsLUeyHlJtlHxe/assets/static/optimized/rev-029371b/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Different-Parts-of-the-VB-Editor-in-Excel.png

Comment: @niton Still i don't untderstand what you wrote....the script is on Excel VBA, how can I select the item in the sent folder or in the inbox? if I run your command in the immediate panel i get Runtime error 424

Comment: This is to determine whether the ReadReceiptRequested property of the item is True after the item was sent. Click on the item in Outlook to select it. Use the command in the Outlook editor.

Comment: I actually found out that the problem was the flag to always request a read receipt: with this flag turned off, the command ```ReadReceiptRequested``` is actually working....but in the opposite case, with "always ask for read receipt" flagged and ```ReadReceiptRequested``` not in the script, the read requests are not sent.....mistery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance in the loop:

```
Do Until (a condition)
    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
```

I'd recommend creating an Application instance once then re-use it with each iteration instead.

The [Application.CreateItemFromTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate) function creates a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) and returns the new item. Read more about this method in the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article. So, the returned object is a `MailItem` most probably.

The [MailItem.ReadReceiptRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.readreceiptrequested) property returns a boolean value that indicates `true` if a read receipt has been requested by the sender. You may expect a [ReportItem object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reportitem?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3007);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) received back when the original email is opened by the recipient. The `ReportItem` object is similar to a `MailItem` object, and it contains a report or error message from the mail transport system.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve my purpouse by editing  the outlook template file: in the FIle-->options panel,  I unflagged the option "always request the read receipt", and flagged just the flag to request the read receipt FOR THE SINGLE MESSAGE, and of course it applies to all the mails for the macro.

**I leave the question still opened because I am interested into implementing a solution with  VBA.**